# mvn version:display-dependency-updates giving an error org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.NoPluginFoundForPrefixException:

Tags: java

I am facing error when I try to run mvn version:display-dependency-updates in local system.

org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.NoPluginFoundForPrefixException: No plugin found for prefix 'version' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.mortbay.jetty, org.codehaus.mojo, org.sonatype.maven.plugins, org.apache.maven.plugins]

I have tried below commands

mvn version:display-dependency-updates
mvn dependency:analyze-duplicate
mvn enforcer:enforce -X

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.3.0:enforce (enforce-banned-dependencies) on project 
[ERROR] Rule 0: org.apache.maven.enforcer.rules.dependency.BannedDependencies failed with message:

[ERROR]com.ebay.aero:aero-perfmon:jar:2.4.0
[ERROR]com.ebayinc.platform.config:config-client-impl:jar:5.2.0
[ERROR] org.apache.maven:maven-artifact:jar:3.6.1 <--- banned via the exclude/include list